# Integrating a script language into a C++ application

Tags: c++, python, scripting, embedding

I'm really new to C++ and I've come across a problem I've not been able to solve by reading documentations.

I want to embed a script language into my c++ application. That language could be javascript, lua or preferably python.

I'm not looking for something like Boost.Python / swig, something that is able to wrap my c++ functions / classes to a python interface, but rather a `python_evaluate_and_return_result_as_variable("my_code");` function.

I have a whole bunch of structs containing a few integers:

```
struct my_integers {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
};
```

Now I want to do some math with these integers, for example:

```
i.a = i.c * i.e;
```

The math I want to do will be changing a lot in the future and I need people other then me be able to change the math without having access to the c++ code.

I'm thinking about a code structure like this:

1. I initialize my struct and fill it with the starting values
2. I load an external python function, lets say "my_python_function", that takes the struct as an argument and does so math with it before returning it.
3. I get my struct like `i = my_python_function_cppwrapper(i)`

Is something like that possible? I googled a lot for this but the only thing I seem to find are wrappers that provide c++ -> python (or the other way around) functionallity without really interacting with variables.

I'd be really thankful for any help,
Robin.

Comment: Why not Boost.Python? It works and will let you do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use Boost.Python? You can expose your data classes to Python and execute a script/function as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I've been looking for. I must've missed the section when I looked over Boost.Python.

Answer (score 8):

The Python documentation has a page on [embedding Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) in a C or C++ application.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to simply run Python scripts from C/C++, then use [the Python C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html).  In your C/C++ code:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import math; x = math.sqrt(2 * 2)");
```

For more complicated things, you will have to look at the API docs, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: That doesn't quite work for me as I need to pass and extract variables, but thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

How about embedding a JavaScript engine, such as [V8](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/intro.html)?

Comment: I think I'm sticking with python but I may use V8 in my next project. Thanks for the hint, the only javascript engine I could think about was spidermonkey.

Answer (score 1):

dont forget the grand-daddy of embedded scripting language - tcl.

tcl has v nice c++ wrapper (modelled on boost.python) that makes it trivial to invoke and to wire up callbacks to your code

Answer (score 1):

Lua works pretty well too, especially since its small, is ansi c compliant, has a low memory foot print along with a great wiki and messaging list. If you need even more speed there is a x86 32 and 64 bit jit version(luajit). Binding can be done with an array of tools/libraries, like swig or lunar(the wiki lists them all). The only problem that i can see is binding the struct members so they can be referenced directly(ie: struct.member = 4), though its possible to set this up with metatables that have get and set methods bound to variable names

Answer (score 1):

You say that you're not looking for something to wrap your C++ functions / classes in a Python interface, but if you want Python code to be able to refer to members of your C++ `my_integers` structure, that *is* wrapping C++ classes in a Python interface.  Of course, you're free to wrap as many or as few classes as you want - in this example, you'd wrap `my_integers`, then you'd [embed a Python interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) to do stuff with `my_integers`.

Answer (score 1):

For something as simple as you describe, you could implement an interpreter for your own 'little language'. You could even call it the "Robin" language. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I advice using **[Lua](http://www.lua.org/)** as internal scripting engine. Implementation is just a few lines, and though light, the language has sufficient power. So no need for TCL. You might as well look at python, integration in C++ is rather easy, as there exists a **[Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)** implementation facilitating integration.

But depending on the application, I'd still recommend Lua.